# How do I find the difference while comparing two similar lines

Tags: unix, grep

I have a log file which has the following log statements

e.g.

```
Before starting transaction id = <unique number>
After starting transaction id = <unique number>

....

Before starting transaction id = <unique number>
After starting transaction id = <unique number>
```

When I do a simple grep for "Before", I see 400 statements, but
when I do a simple grep for "After", I see 402 statements.

How to find these statements where they don't occur in pair.

Comment: `diff "\`cat file | grep After\`" "\`cat file | grep Before\`"` ?
Not near a bash right now, so I coudln't test it.

Comment: is After line always the next line of Before? if they are paired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if paired before and after should have same `unique number`:

```
awk -F= '{a[$2]++;}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]!=2)print "id:"i}' file
```

will print those unpaired ids.

e.g.:

```
kent$  cat file
Before starting transaction id = 1
After starting transaction id = 1
Before starting transaction id = 2
After starting transaction id = 2
Before starting transaction id = 3
Before starting transaction id = 4
After starting transaction id = 4
After starting transaction id = 5

kent$  awk -F= '{a[$2]++;}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]!=2)print "id:"i}' file
id: 3
id: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract the `Before` and `After` ids and then diff them, like this:

```
$ diff -wb <(grep Before file | cut -d= -f2 | sort) <(grep After file | cut -d= -f2 | sort)
```

If your shell does not support [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) i.e. `<(...)`, then use temporary files:

```
$ grep Before file | cut -d= -f2 | sort > before
$ grep After file | cut -d= -f2 | sort > after
$ diff -wb before after
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is not the best too for the job, since it can't read multiple lines. You could read them in pairs with -B1, but you are still left with parsing that with more powerful tools like `sed`, `awk` or others.

Here's another approach that also works in case you get extraneus Before lines (the `echo` being there just so you can dry-run it):

```
$ echo 'Before starting transaction id = 123
After starting transaction id = 123
After starting transaction id = 54675
Before starting transaction id = 567
After starting transaction id = 567' | 
  sort -k6 | uniq -u -f5 # end cmd
After starting transaction id = 54675
```

It works by checking for only unique ids. Since I don't know what kind of content you get in there, maybe they are duplicates of existing entries, in which case you would have to do it differently. Here's the safer approach, which catches both cases and returns the occurences with ID frequency of more or less than 2:

```
$ echo 'Before starting transaction id = 123
After starting transaction id = 123
After starting transaction id = 567
Before starting transaction id = 567
After starting transaction id = 567' | 
  sort -k6 | uniq -c -f5 | grep -v "^[[:space:]]*2[[:space:]]"
3 After starting transaction id = 567
```